# Whats the simplest way of changing the color of a range slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to use a **range** for an input tag. I also want to use standard HTML. So

```
<input type="range">
```

What is the easiest way of styling the bar **before and after** the thumb?

I want to have **two colours**: **One before the thumb** and another colour after.

I played along with JavaScript, but all the solutions were big and uneasy to handle.

I am using AngularJS for my WebApp, so:

- Can anybody recommend an Angular PlugIn?
- Is a jQuery Range-Slider easier to handle then the standard one?
- Are there any CSS Selectors to use?

Comment: It's unlikely that you will get consistent results cross-browser. Some let you customise standard inputs (Chrome for one) and some don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `<input type="range">`, I assume that support for older browsers is not an issue. This solution relies on `background-size`, which is not supported in IE < 8 (http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

This fiddle demonstrates how it could be done in jQuery;

http://jsfiddle.net/LP5XA/

It's simply a background images in the slider, that stretches when the slider is moved.

Comment: I have improved it at bit. You're now allows to have two different background-colors :)

http://jsfiddle.net/LP5XA/1/